# How to search for contacts by date added or date range added. Alternately: list contacts by date added

Tags: search, custom-search, advanced-search

How to search for contacts by date added or date range added. Alternately: list contacts by date

Answer (score 8):

Under Search - Custom Searches - Date Added to CiviCRM.

Also a variation is under Search - Advanced Search, and expand the Change Log tab.